# Loop only showing the last array element ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3

This is my ActionScript3 Code I made two text fields and assign them textformats, and two array. I want the value of array to be in new text field with each iteration of for loop.But it is only showing the last element value of array.I think there is some problem with y position.Thanks in advance.

```
var heading:Array = ["Home","About","Services","Contact"];
var subheading:Array = ["MyData","AboutUs","ServicesProvided","ContactUS"];
var i:int = 0;
var j:int = 0;

var headformat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
headformat.size = 20;
headformat.color = 0xFFFFFF;
headformat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;

var subformat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
subformat.size = 15;
subformat.color = 0x000000;
subformat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;

var headtext:TextField = new TextField();
headtext.width = 200;
headtext.text
headtext.height = 50;
headtext.background = true;
headtext.defaultTextFormat = headformat;
headtext.backgroundColor = 0x0000FF;


var subtext:TextField = new TextField();
subtext.width = 200;
subtext.height = 50;
subtext.background = true;
subtext.backgroundColor = 0xCCCCCC;
subtext.defaultTextFormat = subformat;



for(i=0;i<heading.length;i++)
{
    headtext.text = heading[i];
    headtext.y = j;
    addChild(headtext);
    j+= 60;
    subtext.text = subheading[i];
    subtext.y = j;
    addChild(subtext);
    j+=60;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use the same instance of the text boxes
just put creation of text boxes into the loop, so for each iteration it will create another instance of the text box.

```
var headtext:TextField;
var subtext:TextField;

    for(i=0;i<heading.length;i++)
    {
            headtext = new TextField();
            headtext.width = 200;
            headtext.text
            headtext.height = 50;
            headtext.background = true;
            headtext.defaultTextFormat = headformat;
            headtext.backgroundColor = 0x0000FF;


            subtext = new TextField();
            subtext.width = 200;
            subtext.height = 50;
            subtext.background = true;
            subtext.backgroundColor = 0xCCCCCC;
            subtext.defaultTextFormat = subformat;


            headtext.text = heading[i];
            headtext.y = j;
            addChild(headtext);
            j+= 60;
            subtext.text = subheading[i];
            subtext.y = j;
            addChild(subtext);
            j+=60;
    }
```